# change the flex spacing between div with background image

Tags: html, css, flexbox, spacing

hi i am remaking the google chrome home page but i cant seem to do the part at the bottom of the page were the most used apps are i am trying to do it with display flex because it puts it inline but i cant get the spacing right its uneven or to big or small here is what i want it to look like...
[image]

and here is what i get

[image]
[image]
[image]
the top one is what i need to get.
notice that the spacing is to small
and in the middle its to big i am looking for it to be just right
justify-content doesn't seem to  effect spacing?
here is the css

```
.youtube{
background-image: url(youtube.png);


}
.facebook{
background-image: url(facebook.png);

}

.roblox{
background-image: url(roblox.png);


}

.Agar{
 background-image: url(Agar.png);


  }

    .gmail{
background-image: url(gmail.png);


 }
  .rowCell{
justify-content: space-around;
align-items: center;
position: relative;  
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 200px;
height: 150px;
margin-top: -589px;
left: 422px;
 }
  .mostUsedApps{
     width: 42%;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
justify-content: space-around;
align-items: center;
}
```

here is the html

```
   <div class = 'mostUsedApps'>

   <div class = 'youtube rowCell'></div>

   <div class = 'facebook rowCell'   ></div>

   <div class = 'roblox rowCell'></div>


   <div class = 'Agar rowCell'></div>

   <div class = 'gmail rowCell'></div>

   </div>
```

Any help is much appreciated,thanks :)

Comment: Hello! Please provide a JSBin link with all your actual code. Thanks!

Comment: `.mostUsedApps { justify-content: space-between; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your icons are of same size, then you would just need the `justify-content` property on your parent div i.e. ***"mostUsedApps"***.

If they are of different size, then you would need to provide a link to codepen or codesandbox, without that it would be difficult to help.

Comment: The padding/margin is different between each icon, so this is obviously wrong.

Comment: How do we know that padding/margin is different for each icon ?

Comment: If you look at his picture, the margin is bigger for the icon in the center, than the 2nd and 4th icon

Comment: That is what I asked the author in my answer, we do not really know the size of the icons. The code provided (earlier, when I answered this) did not have any css related to icons' margin or padding. So the only other explanation is the icons might of different size.

Comment: the icons are all the same size all the css for rowcell is for each icon